# My previous theory was wrong, so why does this work?

Tags: arduino, resistance, photoresistor

Hi I am new to electronics, and I have made a light tripwire using an Arduino Uno. I made this on the idea that electricity follows the path of least resistance, which I now know to be false (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/electricity-takes-the-path-of-least-resistance).
False or not however, my tripwire works exactly as I would expect it to.

I programmed my board to sound an alarm if pin 2 reads low voltage
I thought it worked because if the photoresistor has less resistance than the resistor, then it would read high voltage and vice versa. So can anyone explain what is happening?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foJzzh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to electronics and don't know the resistance of R1 (I don't know how to read colour codes).

Comment: too bad that there are no resources on the interwebs on how to easily read them

Comment: Lookup voltage dividers and calculate the voltage at your pin for various light situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a voltage divider. "The path" does not change. The current changes, because the total resistance `LDR1+R1` changes while the voltage applied remains fixed, so the voltage across R1 (which is what you are measuring at U1 pin 2) changes.

Comment: Cool thanks, that sounds like what i'm looking for.